# Show Media Preview Image on Views

Tags: 7, views, media

I want to show the Preview Image from [Media Youtube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube) videos in Views. But I can't figure out how to display them in views. Is it supported? How?

Comment: barraponto, Were you successful in creating a View of Media Assets?? I am trying to create a grid of YouTube Videos in my Media. I cant figure out how to do it Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out: visit **admin/config/media/file-types** and pick the file type you want to edit (Youtube media are Videos). Pick one of the file displays (Small, Big, Original) and enable the Youtube Preview Image display. Finally, pick an image style in the dropdown menu.

Then, visit the Manage Display tab. If you previously chose the Small file display, for example, edit the Display to make sure the File will be shown.

Comment: If you think the UI is way too complicated as it is, please join the Media sprint http://groups.drupal.org/node/173749

Comment: do you have a tutorial on how to have your fields behaving differently on a per views basis ?

Comment: @tostinni you might like the Display Suite module.