# Wrapping a rendered file from Media with a link

Tags: theming, media

This is a question related to [How to set Media Styles in Media 7.1.2 / Media 7.2.X?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40229/how-to-set-media-styles-in-media-7-1-2-media-7-2-x).

I am using [Media 1.2](http://drupal.org/project/media) in a Drupal 7 site to add some fields to images (caption, credit, etc).

If I have an image field set up to display as a **Rendered file** with a particular view mode, eg

[image]

I have my display set up the way I want to show the proper fields for this view mode.  In the file display, eg

[image]

is there a way to wrap the image in a link to the media/fid page?  I am not seeing how to do this from the UI, and [Theme Developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) isn't giving me any useful info for which theme functions and preprocess/process functions are being invoked between the one for the whole image field (as far as the content type is concerned) and the image itself (the actual <img/> element).

At this point, I do not want to switch to Field Collection, but would entertain switching to Media 2.x if that is my only option.

Comment: Did you consider using `hook_field_attach_view_alter()`?

Comment: Not terribly familiar with using that hook, but I didn't see how that would work.

Comment: Its purpose is to alter the way a field is rendered, and it is invoked when [field_attach_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_view/7), or [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7) is called. Using that hook, you should be able to alter how the image field is rendered.

Comment: What happens when you also select _Rendered file_, in _Enabled displays_?

Comment: That display mode is an icon+link to the original file.  The problem is more figuring out who calls the theme('image_style') for the options I outline, but I cannot figure this out.  My next option is to make a MYTHEME_image_style so I can start looking at call stacks.  Joy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, Media renders fields via Drupal's field display formatter mechanism. Your custom module will work, but there is one for this: [Linked Field](http://drupal.org/project/linked_field)

Comment: This does look like a better option, but it keeps blowing up on this particular site.  I need to work this into one of my testing sites and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

OK, here is the working code.

The Media module implements [`hook_file_formatter_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.api.php/function/hook_file_formatter_info/7) to set up a callback for rendering images.

As is the Drupal way there is a [`hook_file_formatter_info_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.api.php/function/hook_file_formatter_info_alter/7) to change the default behavior.  So, I took the default callback from file_entity.module and cloned it into a custom module.  I then wired this up with the alter.  My custom callback has some additional logic to check for an image style, and then wrap the element with a link.

The only real quirk is that the default implementation of [`theme_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_link/7) assumes it is a leaf element, so you need to render out the image element first.

As a side note, this is also how you would get alt/title text onto the images, which is missing by default.

```
function MYMODULE_file_formatter_info_alter(&$info) {
  if (!empty($info['file_image'])) {
    $info['file_image']['view callback'] = 'MYMODULE_file_formatter_file_image_view';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_file_formatter_file_image_view($file, $display, $langcode) {
  // Prevent PHP notices when trying to read empty files.
  // @see http://drupal.org/node/681042
  if (!$file->filesize) {
    return;
  }

  // Do not bother proceeding if this file does not have an image mime type.
  if (strpos($file->filemime, 'image/') !== 0) {
    return;
  }

  if (file_entity_file_is_local($file) && $image = image_load($file->uri)) {
    if (!empty($display['settings']['image_style'])) {
      $element = array(
        '#theme' => 'image_style',
        '#style_name' => $display['settings']['image_style'],
        '#path' => $file->uri,
        '#width' => $image->info['width'],
        '#height' => $image->info['height'],
      );
      if ($display['settings']['image_style'] == 'MYSTYLE') {
        $element = array(
          '#theme' => 'link',
          '#text' => drupal_render($element),
          '#path' => 'media/' . $file->fid,
          '#options' => array(
            'attributes' => array(),
            'html' => TRUE,
          ),
        );
      }
      else {
      }
    }
    else {
      $element = array(
        '#theme' => 'image',
        '#path' => $file->uri,
        '#width' => $image->info['width'],
        '#height' => $image->info['height'],
      );
    }
    return $element;
  }
}
```

Comment: In the project I'm working on loading image on each call using `image_load` causes _huge_ performance problems. If you look into default implementation of `file_entity_file_formatter_file_image_view`, you'll see that you could get image sizes with `$file->image_dimensions` array by `width` and `height` keys.