# Wrapping a rendered file from Media module with a link

Tags: media

This is a question related to [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51481/wrapping-a-rendered-file-from-media-with-a-link).

I'm using [Media 2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) to create an image field, called Background Images, in my custom content type. A user is able to upload multiple Background Images and then these are displayed as rendered files.

I'd like to wrap each Background Image in a link redirecting to another distinct page that will then use that same image by pulling it in from the URL along with the node it is associated with. From the post I linked to above, I saw that the [Linked Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/linked_field) module was an option.

I've been able to configure by going to Structure > Content Types > [my_content_type] > Manage Display > Background Image > Link this field

where the destination I am asking it to go to is:

node/add/canvas?field_movie_parent=[node:nid]&field_background_image_reference=[node:field_background_image_reference]

But I end up getting:

node/add/canvas?field_movie_parent=%5Bnode%3Anid%5D&field_background_image_reference=%5Bnode%3Afield_background_image_reference%5D

If I hard code the values, I can redirect to the page successfully, e.g. where field_movie_parent=1 and field_background_image_reference=1. I'm having trouble with how to dynamically generate the values and am wondering if this is even the right approach. Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.