# How do I apply a defined Image Style as a View Mode for a File field?

Tags: media, entities

I'm currently working my way through O'Reilly's "Using Drupal", but I appear to have reached an impasse.

I'm trying to specify a view mode for a File field-type which utilises the Media File Selector widget. The problem is, I'm not getting any of my set Image Styles in the View Mode drop-down. I'm just getting:

- default
- teaser
- Full Content etc.

(see screenshot of view mode options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXtj.png)
(this screenshot shows my image styles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssFBk.png)

The book was published April 2012 so I'm not sure if anything might have changed significantly since then? I'm using the most up-to-date version of Drupal and all modules.

Can anyone tell me if this is wrong way to perform this task, and if so what the right way is?

Cheers!

Comment: FYI it's Drupal 7, in case you hadn't guessed.

Comment: Looks like "View Mode" refers to the context in which the content is being displayed - not your image derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that things have changed.

Applying image styles is now done exclusively through the structure->file types->images menu.

More extensive instruction can be found in this answer: [How to set Media Styles in Media 7.1.2 / Media 7.2.X?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40229/how-to-set-media-styles-in-media-7-1-2-media-7-2-x/40685#40685)