# In the File Entity module, what is the difference between "Manage display" and "Manage file display"?

Tags: media, files

As per the screenshot, what is the difference between "Manage display" and "Manage file display"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manage display is the core page to manage the display of fields for various view modes.

The Manage file display tab is provided by the File Entity module; the page callback for that tab is [`file_entity_file_display_form()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.admin.inc/function/file_entity_file_display_form/7), whose description is:

> Form callback; presents file display settings for a given view mode.

So the difference is that display settings that relate to the file entity module have been separated out from the core Manage Display form, on a per view-mode basis, and that extra tab is where you set them.

As noted in the comments this is covered in a lot more detail as part of a [broader question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/40685/2800)

Comment: Is there a reason why they would separate this? This is the first time I have seen this? All implementations of entities I have seen just use the standard core "Manage display".

Comment: Reflecting on this a bit more, it is probably because the core "Manage display" is too limiting, which is most likely the cause for my related question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83500/in-the-file-entity-module-what-is-the-purpose-of-multiple-enabled-displays-an

Comment: Yep I think you're right, the format of the core display page doesn't really allow for what the file entity module needs to do

Comment: It appears my question is answered in another broader question on this site. Not sure if I should close this one or not though. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40229/how-to-set-media-styles-in-media-7-1-2-media-7-2-x

Comment: That's a much better answer but I think your question's specific enough that it should stay open. I'll add a link to the better answer so it's more visible