# Add media in CKeditor and image styles

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, media

[image]

The above screen shot is from **`Add media`** button in the CKeditor of drupal article content, and after selecting an image from the library. What I need to see in this window is a list of drupal's image styles in the **`Current format is`**. I'v tried to use [insert module](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) but it only works with image or file fields.

I need any tool or module that allows me to choose image from the library and insert it styled with drupal's image styles in the CKeditor!

Comment: Did you read this 
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40229/how-to-set-media-styles-in-media-7-1-2-media-7-2-x?